# Strage issue with document path

Tags: iphone, ios, epub

I am working on a ebook reader app. The issue i am facing is with loading a Kannada ebook.

I am loading xhtml files from document dir. to UIWebView.

Now the problem is,

If i give path to file like `.../OPS/xhtml/ch1.xhtml` 
   Then the text is not displaying properly , but all images in book are displaying.

If i give path to file like `.../OPS/xhtml//ch1.xhtml` 
    Then the text is displaying properly , but images in book are not displaying.

I am not able to figer out why this is happening and what is the solution.

Comment: You need to include more information to answer this. What is the structure of the files in the ebook? What do the references to the images inside the ebook look like as paths? This question suggests that you are not correctly normalizing all the path references relative to the ebook's document root (which is wherever the book author decided to put the OPF file).